# How to create an Image in rails ? ( from as imagecreate () in php)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I need to create an image from the imagemagick/rmagick library, How should I do that?
as in php it was done like below with GD library.

```
 <?php 
      header ("Content-type: image/png"); 
      $handle = ImageCreate (130, 50) or die ("Cannot Create image"); 
      $bg_color = ImageColorAllocate ($handle, 255, 0, 0); 
      ImagePng ($handle); 
  ?>
```

In input, I have given image color, image co-ordinates of area tag like that..any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`ImageMagick`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) installed in your system and [`rmagick`](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) gem, then:

```
image = Magick::Image.new(130, 50)
image.background_color = 'red'
image.write('someimage.png')
```

Make sure, you have ImageMagick compiled with PNG support.

To send your image, you may do next thing:

```
send_data image, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
```

Then you don't need to save an image unless you want to cache it.

[More information about usage you can find here](https://rmagick.github.io/usage.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I used to create an inline image on the fly:

```
@placeholder = Magick::Image.new(@book.width, @book.height)
@placeholder.format = "png"
@placeholder = "data:image/png;base64,#{Base64.encode64 (@placeholder.to_blob)}"
```

And:

```
<img src="<%= @placeholder %>" />
```

It's not pretty, but it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/usage.html#reading

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick
# Create a 100x100 red image.
f = Image.new(100,100) { self.background_color = "red" }
f.display
exit
```

Comment: Hi anand, I need to have an image with like line graph with given co-ordinate .. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ManishShrivastava if you want a graph, then I recommend using the ChartKick gem.